# How to Link Static Libraries(.a files) with APK using gradle experimental plugin 0.2.0 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

There are two things in my project.

1. I am creating a static library using `ndk-build`
2. Link that Static library to the existing application in Android Studio.

Referred many questions and tried many replies. But none of them works for me.

Here are my doubts,

1. Where actually should the static libraries placed..?
2. How to specify the Gradle build system that I am linking static library..?

Please help me with required steps to follow.

Comment: You can directly use a static library inside an android application. The native library should always be dynamic library (.so). Did gradle compile somme C/C++ code that need to be link with your static library ? If not, you should compile your library to be a dynamic library (.so).

Comment: Do you have access to the header files of these static libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

Modify the build.gradle file of the application... as below

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "AEC"
    ldLibs += ["android", "OpenSLES", "log"]
    ldFlags += "/home/lone/AndroidStudioProjects/AcousticEchoCanceller/app/src/main/jni/prebuilt/libToneDetect.a"
    ldFlags += "/home/lone/AndroidStudioProjects/AcousticEchoCanceller/app/src/main/jni/prebuilt/libAec.a"
    CFlags += ['-std=c99']
}
```

Note: This works only if library and architecture are same. And the apk is building for only 1 Platform

Answer (score 2):

The gradle-experimental 0.2.0 is pretty old for now. I have a solution for 0.7.2.

put this OUTSIDE of the Android{}

```
repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        yourlib {
            headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/prebuilts/include"
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/prebuilts/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libyourlib.so")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this code INSIDE the Android{}

```
   sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    library "yourlib" linkage "shared" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the code come from:[Xavier Hallade post](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/)

Comment: This only works for `sharedLibraryFile`.  What about static libs??

Comment: Igor. have you tried changing "SharedLibraryBinary" to "StaticLibraryBinary",  "sharedLibraryFile" to "staticLibraryFile" and "shared" to "static" ?

Comment: @Arkady , I have tried with `StaticLibraryBinary` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Partho Biswas , can you share more details ? f.ex. your gradle file ,and project structure ?

Answer (score 1):

[Hello-libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) is the one that might be helpful too: it builds 2 libs and use them in the app. The building libs and using libs could be de-coupled; for usage, look at the app/build.gradle

the sample are for shared lib; follow the comment above gperf for static lib in that build.gradle [do not put static lib into jniLibs folder, no need], it will work.

CMake + android studio is similar and simpler [they are in master-cmake branch]

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure is relatively important when referencing a static library, I'm going to indicate the structure of mine, obviously it is going to be slightly different for you but hopefully this clears things up a bit. Firstly:

in my (C:) Drive I have a folder called Projects which is a home to all my Android studio projects, in this folder I have my Library, along with the root direc of the App I'm working on (Which uses the library)

The next step would be to open the project you want to use the library in and include these few lines of code.

Expand "Gradle Scripts" and open 'build.gradle(module:app)' and under dependencies add this - compile project(path: ":library")

Next open 'settings.gradle(Project Settings)' and you should see this - include ':app'

Edit the above line to read include ':app', ':library'
and on the line below add this - 'project(":library").projectDir = new File("../(yourlibraryfoldernamehere)/library")'

That SHOULD do the trick, hopefully this helps, if anything is unclear give me a shout and I'll try assist or explain better! Good luck!

Comment: yourlibraryfoldernamehere is it the absolute path of the library folder..?

Comment: Yes, in my case I have it as ("../Library/library")

Comment: I have created a folder Library in the project folder and plcaed my library libnative.a in that.   In the dependencies 'compile project(':library')' added this and in the settings.gradle 'include ':app', ':library'
project(":library").projectDir = new File("Library/libandroid_vajra.a")' done this. Now when i try to sync the project it is giving the error **Gradle Sync Failed: Configuration with name 'default not found' **

Comment: From past experience the error means somewhere in your file tree there is something named incorrectly, try this then rebuild and see if it works. new File("../libandroid_vajra.a")